# regular expression PHP alphabetic, numeric and default symbols

Tags: regex

This is the regular expression that I am using atm in PHP:

```
preg_match('/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value)
```

So that will do only alphabetic and numeric characters, now I need to add these symbols to be allowed in the regular expression: comma, question mark, dot, and @. How can I do this, sorry for the question I know its kinda easy but I hate regex :P

Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the class:
    `preg_match('/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9,@.\?]+$/', $value)`

I'm not sure that the question mark needs to be escaped, but I'm sure that the dot need not be escaped inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/^[\sa-zA-Z\d,@.?]+$/', $value)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible, you should use:

```
/^[\p{L}\p[N}\s,?.@]+$/
```

Have a look at this [site](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/)